# M.2 to M.2 SSD, replace smaller with larger drive with a single M.2 slot

Tags: 16.04, boot, upgrade, ssd

Hopefully somebody knows a step-by-step approach to this situation.

1. I have an Ubuntu 16.04 PC with a single M.2 SSD and a regular 2 terabyte HDD for storage.
2. The M.2 SSD is the boot and OS drive which is too small and I must replace it for a larger M.2 SSD.
3. The motherboard has only one M.2 slot, I cannot run two M.2 drives side by side.
4. Background: The system is delicately balancing machine learning libraries which I must not upset. Knowing how much work its taken to get this going I don't want to upset a thing. I want to avoid fumbling around swapping drives and risking unintended consequences.

I need to get a complete clone off the current M.2 SSD onto the new larger M.2 SSD so the current setup doesn't have a clue anything happened and it all boots up magically on the larger M.2 drive.

The tools we have are:

- 2 terabyte HDD on the system that could be used to hold a clone image of the current M.2 SSD if required.
- a bootable USB stick.
- two M.2 SSDs, one with the current OS setup and 1 new larger blank ssd.

I don't want to mess this up. How do I get the complete working copy off the old M.2 to the new bigger M.2 in as few a steps as possible with a minimum of risk?

Answer (score 4):

I would use **Clonezilla**, http://clonezilla.org, for this task. Download an iso file and make a USB boot drive with Clonezilla.

Let Clonezilla create a compressed Clonezilla image in a partition of the 2 TB  HDD. (The image is a directory with several files.)

Then you can swap the m.2 ssd sticks and restore from the compressed Clonezilla image into the new and bigger ssd stick.

The result is a cloned image, with the same size of the partitions. Test that it works.

When you know that it works, you can boot from a USB boot drive with **gparted** (for example an Ubuntu live drive) and use gparted to edit the partition table, to take advantage of whole drive, [to 'grow' the partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=GrowIt.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I reckon @sudodus approach with Clonezilla. Very straightforward. I followed this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS6VhLDw-io

My setup: Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 7 with 256GB M.2 and Win 10.

Goal: Upgrade the M.2 to 1TB for dual boot with existing Win 10 and new Linux.

1. Created a bootable Clonezilla USB drive with this image here (https://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative).
2. Plugged the 256GB and 1TB into my desktop and booted into Clonezilla.
3. Followed almost one to one the steps of the youtube video. The only change I did was to leave out the intermediate step of saving the image to a hard drive and then recovering. I immediately cloned the 256GB M.2 to the 1TB M.2 by selecting during the Clonezilla set up "device-device" instead of "device-image". The process took around 25 minutes. The process was smooth and my X1 booted without problems into the new drive with the cloned Win 10.
4. Booted into a live USB to expand the drive or partition it as I wished.

Answer (score 0):

The following method will not touch your existing m.2.

I am assuming you are using ext4 and you are using GPT. That /dev/sda is your m.2 and that your 2TB drive is mounted to /mnt. *I am also assuming that your do not have a partition after the OS partition.* If you do then you'd need to move it first. First copy your partition table.

gdisk /dev/sda
then press B and type /mnt/2tbdrive/part.dat

Then make a copy of the disk for each partition:

partclone.ext4 -c -s /dev/sda2 -o /mnt/2tbdrive/OS.img

This will copy only allocated sectors of the file system into the image file. You will need to repeat this step for each ext4 file system. For EFI system partition:

partclone.fat32 -c -s /dev/sda1 -o /mnt/2tbdrive/EFI.img

Now switch to the new device.

gdisk /dev/sda
then type R then type L then /mnt/2tbdrive/part.dat
Use P to check that it loaded correctly.
Use D to delete the partition you want to enlarge.
Use N to create a new partition then select the next partition number. The first sector needs to the same sector as before. The output from P will tell you this but it should already be defaulted to it. The last sector should expand to the end of the disk. Then give it the same file system type which will probably be the default. Use P to confirm again that it worked.
and then type W to write changes to disk.

Now restore your partitions:

partclone.fat32 -r -s /mnt/2tbdrive/EFI.img -o /dev/sda1

partclone.ext4 -r -s /mnt/2tbdrive/OS.img -o /dev/sda2

Note that this will create drives with the exact same UUIDs so you should not have to reconfigure anything. You do however need to expand your file system.

Finally do resize2fs /dev/sda which will enlarge the file system.